# Can't deploy camel service to jboss Fuse

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-jdbc, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse

I'm trying to deploy a Camel service in JBoss Fuse but when I type "start (bundleId)" I get the following error

> Error executing command: Error starting bundles:  Unable to start
>   bundle 435: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.service [435]: Unable
>   to resolve 435.0: missing requirement [435.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.jdbc)

I've included camel-jdbc and spring-jdbc features in it's fabric8 profile but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If you have included the camel-jdbc and spring-jdbc features in your fabric8 profile, then it may be due to a version mismatch somewhere probably.

You can try installing the features using the features:install command and check.

`features:install camel-jdbc`
`features:install spring-jdbc`